# Button's frame is not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIButton` at the position x=0.0. Now when I am pressing that button the button is shifting and goes to a position at x=131.0. Now when I am pressing that again it should come back to x=0.0 position. But its not coming. It is staying at the position x=131.0.

This is the code I have written

```
- (IBAction)showMenuViewButton:(id)sender {

_horizontalConstraintsOfColorViewToMainView.constant = 0.0;
_buttonOfColorViewHoriozontalLeadingConstraints.constant = 131.0;

counter=counter+1;

if (counter%2 !=0) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^
     {
         _menuView.hidden = NO;
         _menuView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, _menuView.frame.origin.y, _menuView.frame.size.width, _menuView.frame.size.height);
         _showMenuViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(_showMenuViewButton.frame.origin.x+_menuView.frame.size.width+_showMenuViewButton.frame.size.width,_showMenuViewButton.frame.origin.y, _showMenuViewButton.frame.size.width, _showMenuViewButton.frame.size.width);


     }];
}
else{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^
     {
         _menuView.hidden = NO;

         _menuView.frame = CGRectMake(-102.0, _menuView.frame.origin.y, _menuView.frame.size.width, _menuView.frame.size.height);
         _showMenuViewButton.frame =    CGRectMake(0.0,_showMenuViewButton.frame.origin.y,     _showMenuViewButton.frame.size.width, _showMenuViewButton.frame.size.width);

     }];

}
}
```

Comment: Have you created IBOutlets for Layout Constraints? If yes, then how are you removing/adding them while adjusting the x coordinate?

Comment: Where am I removing/adding the constraints while adjusting the x coordinate. @Gandalf

Comment: Actually i asked you that as i see some constraints constants being changed in your code. If you are not using constraint then why are they there? Shall i assume that you are relying on frame setting and not the constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here I have changed button frame for animation not change any contarint**

```
 - (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender {
        if (!isChangedPlace) {         
            isChangedPlace = true;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                      animations:^{ 

 btn.frame = CGRectMake(btn.frame.origin.x, btn.frame.origin.y+100, btn.frame.size.width, btn.frame.size[self.height);view layoutIfNeeded];
                                      }];
        }
        else
        {
            isChangedPlace = false;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                             animations:^{
btn.frame = CGRectMake(btn.frame.origin.x, btn.frame.origin.y-100, btn.frame.size[self.width,view btn.frame.size.height);layoutIfNeeded];
                             }];
        }

    }
```

**Here I have change buttons Y constraint for animating it 
I have set Y constraint using IBOutlet and change that value as follow.**

```
    - (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender {
        if (!isChangedPlace) {

            isChangedPlace = true;
             buttonYPointConstraint.constant += 50;

        }
        else
        {
            isChangedPlace = false;
            buttonYPointConstraint.constant -= 50;

        }
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0  animations:^{
   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                                      }];
    }
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: Position is not changing still @Pravin

Comment: iPeter: your problem is solved with above answer. 
Actually there are two ways for that 
1. change frame 
2. change contraint 
which is stable for you use it. :)